# install apps created with unity on ios

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I thank everyone immediately for the help you will give me, I was wondering how I could and if there was a way to download my apps created with Unity on iOS and keep them there "forever" without having to sign up for any subscription

I already installed my app but after a few days it tells me that it is no longer available and I have to install it again from xcode

Comment: An app built with a free developer membership needs to be installed every few days.  An app built with a paid membership will run until your subscription renewal date